# Can I redirect the Thread execution on new command window after calling start() method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have one main program. From it I'm invoking three other programs as three different thread. These three threads uses `while(true)` in their run() method so that they will continue to execute unless and until interrupted. Okay, But I wish to invoke these threads on three different command window. I mean I should be able to see their execution on three different command window separately.

I know there is something called `RunTime.exec()` to open separate command window from java program, but I really don't know how can I redirect the execution of thread to display it on these command windows.

Is it possible in java.

Please help thanks.

Comment: "These three threads uses while(true) in their run() method so that they will continue to execute unless and until interrupted." This is really bad, it will consume your CPU resources. You should instead use the `wait` method or the `Thread.sleep` method (maybe the latter, since you want to interrupt them).

Comment: But these three threads are performing three different actions and collectively achieving one common goal. Assume that these three threads works like active servers which serves the incoming client request and since the request may come anytime so they should not sleep. So I am using `while(true)`. How can I achieve it using `wait` and `sleep`? If possible please elaborate the one. It'd be helpful indeed.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread that as meaning `while(true) {}`. Ignore my comment!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are working on Windows plateform. Then do the following
1. In the run() method of every thread create a new process for CMD as 
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe");
2. Then create an output stream for showing the output of the thread
    OutputStream os = proc.getOutputStream();
3. Now whatever you want to show to the screen, write it into this stream and keep flushing.
    Don't forget close the stream when the thread is to terminate

But this way you shall not be able to interact with the thread directly. For this you need to create input stream and use it the same way.

Comment: Well great Idea, I should try this one, will comment the results. Thanks.

Comment: Its not working. I tried it on windows 7, and Ubuntu as well. Its just opening the terminal window(in ubuntu) but not executing threads on it. In windows 7 its not even opening command window. I really don't know but this's the limitation of java. Isn't it?